# Being told I have an infinite loop, but I'm unsure how to fix it. (Python Coding Course)

Tags: python

I'm currently in a python coding class and this is an assignment. I apparently have an infinite loop somewhere in my code, yet I can't seem to find it.

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
factorial = 1

# check if the number is negative, positive or zero
if num < 0:
 print("Sorry, factorial does not exist for negative numbers")
elif num == 0:
 print("The factorial of 0 is 1")
else:
 for i in range(1,num + 1):
   factorial = factorial*i
print("The factorial of",num,"is",factorial)

# At this point the program should take your now factorial and give you the         fibonacci sequence

# takes your factorial and makes it the fibonacci
nterms = factorial

# first two terms
n1 = 0
n2 = 1
count = 2

# check if the number of terms is valid
if nterms <= 0:
 print("Plese enter a positive integer")
elif nterms == 1:
 print("Fibonacci sequence:")
 print(n1)
else:
 print("Fibonacci sequence:")
 print(n1,",",n2,end=', ')
while count < nterms:
   nth = n1 + n2
   print(nth,end=' , ')
   # update values
   n1 = n2
   n2 = nth
   count += 1
```

I've used both the debugging tool and attempted to find the problem myself by running the programming and attempting various break sequences but I'm just not grasping it.

Comment: You have no infinite loop, when I enter 12 nterms is  `479001600` so you have a long slow loop,  not infinite. Also nth is getting very large so calculation that and printing it also adds overhead.

Comment: What do you mean by "I apparently have an infinite loop somewhere in my code"? Who, or what, is telling you that you have an infinite loop?

Comment: My teacher is telling me I have an infinite loop in my code, which is keeping me from receiving credit.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the assignment and your code is failing to complete in whatever timelimit your teacher is applying. You have no infinite loops.

Comment: To elaborate, I expect you're being asked for `n!` and `fibonacci(n)`, rather than `n!` and `fibonacci(n!)` as you have done.

Comment: I was asked to make a program that took an integer and gave me said factorial of an integer. Then give the Fibonacci sequence of the integer. His exact words in the comment on the 0/50 was 'Apparently you have an infinite loop.  I had to restart Wing.
Fix this.'

Comment: It's kind of sad that your teacher isn't even reading your code. I remember when I had a Unix course several years ago we would actually print out all our assignments (yes, on paper). The teacher wasn't running them to see if they worked; she was _reading_ them to make sure they were _good_.

Comment: Just reading it proves you don't, Each condition will eventually resolve, it just might be slow. Either your teacher hasn't read your code and made assumptions or you need a teacher who actually knows how to code.

Comment: That sounds like your teacher is too lazy to give you proper feedback. It's not infinite, but it's __very, very__ long. You're outputting the first `nterms` Fibonacci numbers. `nterms` is the factorial of `num`, so that's __a lot__. You probably meant to generate the first `num` Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: Rawing I'm following his instructions correctly I think. This is exactly what he told us to do. "Develop a program that takes a positive integer input and calculates three things: 
 
1.  The sum of all integers from 1 up to and including the input integer.  
2.  The factorial of the input integer.  
3.  Use the integer to calculate that number in the Fibonacci sequence listed above. "

Comment: I see what you mean now. It's not infinite but it's super long and is displaying every number instead of just the last number. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Put the `print` after the loop instead of inside it.

Comment: @Rawing - It'll solve "displaying every number instead of just the last number," which is all I intended. :)

Comment: @Packy502: Change your loop to `while count < num:` or see [Jack's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38610188/1222951).

Comment: Would you mind forwarding [my Careers CV](http://stackoverflow.com/cv/tigerhawkt3) to your school's principal (or whoever hires)? I guarantee that I would write clear assignments and actually look at students' programs. :P

Answer (score 2):

There is no infinite loop in your code, both loops will finish in finite time. What is happening is that your teacher, without looking at your code, has discovered that the finite time is very, very long and mistaken this for an infinite loop.

The reason it's taking so long is that you have misunderstood the question - "I was asked to make a program that took an integer and gave me said factorial of an integer. Then give the Fibonacci sequence of the integer" - means find the factorial and Fibonacci sequence of the *same* integer rather than feeding the first result into the second. Simply replace the line `nterms = factorial` with the line `nterms = num` to fix the problem.

(See comments on question for additional information used in this answer)

Answer (score 0):

First, you already know what a loop is and how it works. You should review the loop in your code and make sure any variable used is defined. Since this is an assignment, this is the best I can do for you, to be honest your problem is already solved.

Maybe try enclosing your code in a function with arguments/input-variables, this way your code might run smoother and better. Hope this helps.

Comment: That is valuable feedback, especially for someone learning to program.  I don't see why others have downvoted this.

Comment: @xtofl, probably because it does not answer the question,  feedback can also be posted as a comment as many already have. This also actually confuses the matter as it mentions things that are not happening at all in the code like *make sure any variable used as a condition is defined/declare*.